# Utilização do virtualenv python

Tags: python, virtualenv

Estou começando a usar o virtualenv para projetos e no processo me surgiu uma duvida, depois de ativar o ambiente, toda vez que eu entrar ou sair da pasta ele ativa e desativa automaticamente, ou eu preciso dar activate para usa-lo e deactivate para voltar para configuração global?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ola .

Sobre sua pergunta, sim terá que ativar e desativar.

Mas pode delegar essa função ao sistema operacional em uso caso tenha apenas um ambiente no entanto se estiver  usando ambientes com versões diferentes tera que ser manualmente.

utilizando da seguinte sintaxe :

ATIVAR - (**Gnu/Linux**)

workon DEV38  (Uso python 3.8+)

workon DEV27 ( Uso python 2.7+)

DESATIVAR - (**Gnu/Linux**)

deactivate DEV38

deactivate DEV27

Comment: Jeferson, a pergunta é sobre `virtualenv`, e sua resposta fala sobre `virtualwrapper`. Pelo que pesquisei, nem o [módulo `venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) do Python3 nem a biblioteca [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/index.html) possuem o comando `workon` adicionados ao PATH.

Comment: virtualenv é um criador de ambientes virtuais ,virtualwrapper gerencia.
O uso apenas do virtualenv tera que ativar e desativar.
Tanto um quanto outro é inicializado manualmente.
No entanto caso use sempre uma versão pode especificar.

Os exemplos são apenas uma menção ao ato de ter que ativar
e desativar. activate , deactivate ou até listar lsvirtualenv.
A parte que expliquei é equivalente, o exemplo foi de ativar e desativar.

Answer (score 4):

De forma simplificada, o scritp `activate` modificará as variáveis de ambiente durante a sessão do terminal.

```
[...]

VIRTUAL_ENV="/home/user/python/venv"
export VIRTUAL_ENV

_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH="$PATH"
PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"
export PATH

[...]
```

<sup>Trecho de código retirado do arquivo `venv/bin/activate`</sup>

Ou seja, quando você ativa o ambiente virtual uma variável de ambiente `VIRTUAL_ENV` é criada com o caminho para onde foi gerado o ambiente; logo após ele modifica o valor da variável `PATH` adicionando a variável recém criada como primeiro caminho na busca em PATH.

Desta forma, quando você executar algum comando com o ambiente virtual ativado, o primeiro diretório a ser analisado em busca do executável deste comando será o diretório `venv/bin` (no Windows será `venv/Scripts`).

Ao executar a função `deactivate` as variáveis voltarão ao valor inicial, isto é, a variável `VIRTUAL_ENV` será excluída e a `PATH` voltará ao valor `_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH`, criada durante o `activate` com o valor original de `PATH`.

Ao encerrar a sessão do seu terminal, essas variáveis de ambiente serão removidas, então não existe a obrigação de você sempre chamar o `deactivate`. Necessita executá-lo apenas quando necessita sair do ambiente virtual mantendo a mesma sessão do terminal - comum quando está, por exemplo, conectado via SSH no servidor.

Navegar entre pastas durante a mesma sessão do terminal não fará com que o seu ambiente virtual seja desativado.

Answer (score 1):

Sim, quando for trabalhar no seu projeto será necessário ativar o virtualenv, e quando terminar precisar desativa-la.

Para Windows, é necessário instalar o módulo virtualenv

```
  > pip install virtualenv
```

Depois é necessário criar uma pasta de Venv na raiz do projeto

```
> python -m venv "venv_name"
```

Para ativar a Venv:

```
> venv_name\Scripts\activate.bat
```

Para sair do Venv, digitar:

```
> deactivate
```